# Unexpected error when trying to set up a VPC for my Firebase cloud functions to use a dedicated IP address

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, vpc

I am using Firebase cloud functions as a backend for my app and I want to set up a dedicated IP address using a VPC for my cloud functions since I also need to interact with a Mongo Atlas DB and want to whitelist a single IP address from which it can receive requests as a security measure. According to Firebase docs (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip), it seems this is possible using a workaround of using a VPC.

This is a very murky and uncertain area of programming for me so I am progressing using what I am thinking the docs are telling me.

1. Set up a VPC. I did this using manual setup. When you set up a VPC, and you create a new subnet, it requires you to put in an IP address range that must be valid. According to this document (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#manually_created_subnet_ip_ranges#subnet-ranges), the IP address range 10.0.0.0/8 is a valid IP range. I used this range for my VPC subnet.

NOTE: I tried the other IP addresses in that document but they were invalid and threw an error

THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK vvvvvvv
2) The next step is to set up a VPC serverless access connector. I started to do this. This too requires me to define an IP range. According to this document (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access?&_ga=2.204931472.-1046973627.1608007278#creating_a_connector), the range 10.8.0.0 (/28) "will work in most new projects." However, when I use this range and create the VPC serverless access connector, I get an error that says: "Connector is in a bad state, manual deletion recommended" (see below).

[image]

Again, my end goal is to have a single IP address from which I can connect to my Mongo instance. I think I am going about this correctly, but could be wrong. How can I proceed from this step and silence the error I am getting? Am I doing something wrong in the initial setup? Again, the end goal is to get a single IP address from which I can connect Firebase cloud functions to MongoDB so I can whitelist that IP address on Mongo as a security measure. Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Screenshot of my VPC and subnet
[image]

Comment: Did you try to change the range? What are the current range of your subnets? Can you share a screenshot of your VPC and you subnets?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Just updated with screenshot

Comment: try a serverless VPC connector with this ip range `192.168.0.0/28` and let me know.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Seems to have worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were not able to create a Serverless VPC connector is because the CIDR of your VPC and the CIDR of the connector cannot overlap.

This is well documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector):

> [IP_RANGE] is an unreserved internal IP network, and a '/28' of unallocated space is required. The value supplied is the network in CIDR notation (10.8.0.0/28). This IP range must not overlap with any existing IP address reservations in your VPC network. For example, 10.8.0.0/28 works in most new projects.

In your VPC Serverless connection creation you omitted the most important part

> This IP range must not overlap with any existing IP address reservations in your VPC network.

"The range 10.8.0.0 (/28) will work in most new projects." which is true but "most" does not mean "all" so you should check your settings always.

Since you had `10.0.0.0/8` in your VPC, the CIDR `10.8.0.0/28` overlaps with the VPC CIDR, for this reason and as suggested by @guillaume-blaquiere in the comments, the CIDR `192.168.0.0/28` will work.